# Clarification needed with not-equal operator

Tags: c++, operators

I wrote this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void unequalityOperator(){

   cout << "Running unequalityOperator..." << endl;

   bool a = true, b = false;

   if ( a != b ) cout << "!=" << endl;
   if ( a =! b ) cout << "=!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
   unequalityOperator();

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

And I was surprised that it run and printed both of the strings. So I tried the same thing with some other binary operators like `<=`, `>=`, etc. but it didn't work.
Therefore I would like to understand whether there is a difference between `!=` and `=!`.

I do know that there are some operators like `+=`, `-=`, etc. that work differently and, e.g., the difference between `+=` and `=+` is that the addition will occur before or after (respectively) the actual command. And for this reason I suspect that there is difference with the hierarchy in the implementation of these operators, but I am not really sure what.

So please help me understand.

Comment: `(a =! b)` -> `(a = !b)`

Comment: `(a =! b)` assigns `!b` to `a`. You might also want to have a look at the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of the different operators.

Comment: There is no `++=` or `--=` nor is there a `=++` or `=--`.

Comment: Yep, got carried over with C++ :P - fixed

Comment: @Mechanic45 well, there still is no `operator=+(...)`. You might be thinking of prefix and postfix `++` and `--`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `a = !b` is an assignment of the value `!b` into the variable `a`.

The evaluation of this expression within an `if` statement is the new value of `a`.

Since `b` is set to `false` and you are assigning `!b` into `a`, this value is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In first case the `!=` operator is a single inequality operator. In second case it is an assignment operator `=` with logical not operator `!`. So in the second case you are assigning `not b` to `a` and returning it's result `true`

Answer (score 0):

This might help to clear things up:

- `!=` : not-equal operator
- `=!` : these are really two operators: assignment operator and unary logical NOT operator
- `+=` : sum-assignment operator
- `=+` : these are really two operators: assignment operator and unary + operator
- `-=` : difference-assignment operator
- `=-` : these are really two operators: assignment operator and unary - operator

Also, as these were in your question before being edited out:

- `++=` : two operators: postfix increment operator and assignment operator
- `=++` : two operators: assignment operator and prefix increment operator

I hope you notice the pattern.

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B